# What is the PDF of this scaled non-central chi-squared random variable and what is the result of its integral?

Tags: random-variables, random, density-function, random-functions, chi-squared

Consider a random variable that has a scaled non-central chi-squared
distribution
\begin{eqnarray*}
L & = & a\chi_{1}^{2}(b^{2}),
\end{eqnarray*}
where $a$ is a positive scalar and $\chi_{1}^{2}(b^{2})$ represents
a non-central chi-squared with one degree of freedom. In fact $\chi_{1}^{2}(b^{2})$
is the square of $\mathcal{N}(b,1)$. Denote the probability density
function of $L$ by $p(s)$. What is the formula of $p(s)$ and what
is the result of the following integral 
\begin{eqnarray*}
I & = & \int_{h}^{\infty}p(s)ds
\end{eqnarray*}
please? Thanks.